# MySql Replication with a star topology

Tags: synchronization, mysql-replication, topology

My company currently operates in 3 separate locations connected by slow vpn links. Each site hosts a dedicated MySql server. I need to aggregate the data from all three of them onto a single server for corporate reporting. The powers that be have stated I cannot use circular replication or federated tables. Is there a third party tool for MySql that can replicate from multiple masters? Basically the diagram would be a daisy with the reporting server slave at center with multiple replication connections coming in from the master sites on the petals.

Comment: I don't want to put this as an answer because I'm not sure about this suggestion, I haven't done the research to be sure - but look at MySQL Heartbeat and see if it can do it.  It's meant to do Heartbeat replication in the event that a server goes down - but it might be able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

[pervasync](http://www.pervasync.com/products) seems to be my best bet. Synchronization seems to be the proper verb for my task.